# Create instance of ActionBar Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, instance, abstract-class

Iam using A ActionBar in my app. I have done something like so:-

```
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

But I get a compilation error like:-

```
A object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(bool)'
```

How can I create a instance of ActionBar as it is a Abstract class?

**EDIT:-**

With waquaslam's solution I did this:-

```
public class Homescreen : ActionBarActivity
{

    private DrawerLayout _drawer;
    private MyActionBarDrawerToggle _drawerToggle;
    private ListView _drawerList;
    private static ActionBar ActionBar ;

    private string _drawerTitle;
    private string _title;
    private string[] _planetTitles;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SupportRequestWindowFeature(WindowCompat.FeatureActionBar);



        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.homescreen);




        _title = _drawerTitle = Title;
        _planetTitles = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.TitlesArray);
        _drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        _drawerList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.left_drawer);

        _drawer.SetDrawerShadow(Resource.Drawable.drawer_shadow_dark, (int)GravityFlags.Left);

        _drawerList.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,
            Resource.Layout.drawerlistitem, _planetTitles);
        _drawerList.ItemClick += (sender, args) => SelectItem(args.Position);






        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        //DrawerToggle is the animation that happens with the indicator next to the
        //ActionBar icon. 
        _drawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(this, _drawer,
                                                  Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer_light,
                                                  Resource.String.DrawerOpen,
                                                  Resource.String.DrawerClose);

        //You can alternatively use _drawer.DrawerClosed here
        _drawerToggle.DrawerClosed += delegate
        {
            ActionBar.Title = _title;
            //InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };

        //You can alternatively use _drawer.DrawerOpened here
        _drawerToggle.DrawerOpened += delegate
        {
            ActionBar.Title = _drawerTitle;
            // InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };

        _drawer.SetDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);

        if (null == savedInstanceState)
            SelectItem(0);

    }
```

Now I get  a `NoClassDefinitionFoundError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **support.V7** then make sure your activity inherits from `ActionBarActivity`.

In order to get reference of ActionBar in compatibility library, you must need to use the following:

```
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

For more info, read [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/tab_layout/actionbar/) in which the example is based on Tabs in actionbar but using support library.

Comment: @waqslam I tried your solution. I could get rid of that issue but now Iam facing another issue.PLease see my Edit on `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);` line

Comment: You should not update the question and totally change its direction. In fact post another question, since both of your issues do not relate to each other. Anyhow, it would be more helpful to investigate if you post the exception stack trace from logcat too.